# How to select next matched child-item in an ul and trigger a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me with this problem:

I want to trigger a click event on the next `href` nested inside an unordered list on an keyup-event but I can't get it running.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#pagetop" id="active">Start</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section1">Topic 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">Topic 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section3">Topic 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
    $('#active').next("li a").click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select the succeeding `li` sibling element of the `a#active` element. It doesn't have an `li` sibling elements, but its parent element does.

You need to select the parent, and then select the sibling `li` element from there.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down
    $('#active').parent().next().find('a').click();
  }
});
```

You could also use the `.closest()` method, if the nesting varies:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down
    $('#active').closest('li').next().find('a').click();
  }
});
```

You may actually have to access the first matched DOM element in order to fire the `click` event as well ([since `.click()` is a native DOM element method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)), so you could also try:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down
    $('#active').closest('li').next().find('a')[0].click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it was a long day for me…